# ¿Cómo llegar a la clase quantity?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un Ajax que al detectar un cambio en la cantidad me multiplica los valores, funcionaba bien cuando estaba el input solo

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline quantity text-center" value="{{$item->quantity}}" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" data-id="{{$item->id}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Ahora le agregué los botones para agregar o quitar cantidad, no funciona. Sé que no funciona por las etiquetas padres pero no sé como indicarle donde se encuentra la clase `quantity` ahora

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="input-group number-spinner">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="dwn">-</button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline quantity text-center" value="{{$item->quantity}}" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" data-id="{{$item->id}}">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="up">+</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax como funcionaba

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".quantity").change(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();  
            id = $(this).data("id");
            quantity = ($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('cart.update') }}",
                type:"POST",
                data: {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', id: id, quantity: quantity},
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload(); 
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

He intentado con:

`$(".input-group .quantity").change(function (e) {`, `$(".number-spinner .quantity").change(function (e) {`, `$("div .quantity").change(function (e) {`

pero no lo he logrado

Comment: Hola Joe, no esta claro lo que necesitas. ¿El problema es que al tocar en los btns el evento no se dispara?

Comment: Comparte un poco mas de código... Qué pasa al pulsar cada uno de los botones?

Comment: @Marcos Al presionar los botones aumenta o disminuye el numero del input pero no hace el llamado al ajax

Comment: @DjCrazy al pulsar los botones aumenta o disminuye el número en el input pero no me llama al javascript con la clase "quanty"

Comment: @Joe, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que incrementa/decrementa el valor del input?

Comment: Ese código está en la pregunta, con los signos `- y +` lo hace, lo que no hace es el cálculo ya que es la consulta que hace el ajax, pero el código ajax no se ejecuta una ves que presiono los signos, con el primer bloque funciona perfectamente, pero con el segundo no, eso debido a que la clase `quantity` ahora esta por debajo de `<div class="input-group number-spinner">`, es lo mismo solo que agregué dentro del `input-group` los `span` para los botones `- y +`

Comment: Al haber un cambio en el input, debería hacer el llamado al ajax y no lo está haciendo

Comment: Sí manualmente ingreso el número en el input si hace la función, pero si lo hago a través de los botones no lo hace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema no es el no poder identificar el selector del input (lo cual tampoco tiene que ver con que éste aparezca parcialmente tapado por otro elemento, eso JS no lo sabe).

El problema es que antes cambiabas el valor del input a mano y ahora quieres hacerlo con botones. La manera nueva no gatilla el evento `change`. En la práctica, la propiedad `value` de un input no es observable. Si se modifica via JS como hacen los botones (en mi supuesto) y quieres reaccionar a ese cambio, tienes dos opciones:

La primera, es hacer que los botones, después de modificar el valor, gatillen el evento `change` sobre el input (el código que te dejé acá abajo hace eso)

```js
$('.button_minus').on('click', () => {
  const initialValue = Number($('.quantity').val()),
    newValue = Math.max(initialValue - 1, 0)
  if (initialValue !== newValue) $('.quantity').val(newValue).trigger('change')
});
$('.button_plus').on('click', () => {
  const initialValue = Number($('.quantity').val()),
    newValue = initialValue + 1;
  if (initialValue !== newValue) $('.quantity').val(newValue).trigger('change')
});
$(".quantity").on('change', function(e) {
  $(this).val(Number($(this).val().trim()));
  e.preventDefault();
  id = $(this).data("id");
  quantity = ($(this).val());
  console.log(`quantity changed to: ${quantity}`)

})
```

```css
.button_minus {
  padding: 0 0.5em !important;
  height: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
}

.button_plus {
  padding: 0 0.6em !important;
  height: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-4" style="max-width:200px;">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="input-group number-spinner">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary button_minus"  data-dir="dwn">-</button>
            </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline quantity text-center" value="1" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" data-id="1">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-secondary button_plus"  data-dir="up">+</button>
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero como es incierto qué otros controles o eventos pueden modificar el valor del input, y no tienes certeza si todos están gatillando el evento change al hacerlo, puedes poner un timeInterval (si tienes muchos inputs esto huele a memory leak)

```
let initialValue=$('.quantity').val();
setTimeInterval(()=>{
   if($('.quantity').val() !== initialValue;
   initialValue=$('.quantity').val();
   $('.quantity').trigger('change');
},4000);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, sí es exactamente lo que requiero, la cantidad de inputs los podría limitar quizás, sino evaluar otra opción.